# Webform / add hidden field with token

Tags: webforms, tokens

When adding a hidden secure field to a webform it does not show up in markup. Both for default value and tokens.

> Secure value (allows use of all tokens)

If I choose a hidden element it is present in DOM.

> Hidden element (less secure, changeable via JavaScript)

I have cleared cache several times, rearranged elements with both text fields and normal hidden fields. Those show up, but not the hidden secure ones.

What am I not doing right?

Here's what I'm referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields with **Secure value (allows use of all tokens)** won't appear in your markup (that's why they are secured). They are 'created' on server side and are not available on Client Side. So nobody can't change their value (f.x. via XSS)

Hope it helps.